# GTK+ 3 won't setup/configure in Windows

Tags: windows, gtk

Just recently I tried to install GTK+ on Windows 7 using all-in-one bundle and latest MinGW package. I proceeded with all steps of [official tutorial](http://www.gtk.org/download/win32_tutorial.php/). Lurking through several tutorials, especially [this one](http://gtkwindows.blogspot.ru/2012/09/compiling-first-gtk-program.html) helped me getting MinGW and MSYS set up, so GCC sure works. The command

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0
```

printed out the expected set of paths/options. However, when I tried to run either

```
gcc -o gtk3.exe gtk3.c (pasted 'pkg-config' output)
```

or

```
gcc -o gtk3.exe gtk3.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

I've got

```
gcc: error: gtk3.c: No such file or directory
```

as a result. Searching the file manually was no success as well. It seems that Windows command prompt has torn the original long command apart, but I don't think that it would be this way if GCC has initialized gtk3.c.

I believe that official tutorial can't be wrong, so please help me resolve this problem.

Best regards, Mathias.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows installation tutorial for GTK+ might not be the most thoroughly tested thing... [This](http://www.tarnyko.net/repo/gtk3_build_system/tutorial/gtk3_tutorial.htm) is a better version of that page, it includes a link to the source file (although any GTK+ "hello world" code will do).

You could [file a bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=gtk%2B&component=Website) on the missing link and images as well if you want to help others.

Comment: Many thanks for answering. However, where do I stock *.c files for them to be executed? I've read smth about '-I' option, just don't know where GTK might originally require *.C's to be.

Comment: Well, `gtk3.c` is your application source code: put it anywhere you want. Then you should run gcc in that same directory.

Comment: I don't comprehend. Might it be that command prompt doesn't read backticks? I tried to place my `example-0.c` in /bin folders of both GTK+ and MinGW, then that's what I've got:

Comment: `gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o example-0 example-0.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
gcc: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory
gcc: error: gtk+-3.0`: No such file or directory
gcc: error: example-0.c: No such file or directory
gcc: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory
gcc: error: gtk+-3.0`: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--cflags'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--libs'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.` here i tried to run using GTK+ path

Comment: `gcc -o example-0.exe example-0.c gcc: error: example-0.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.` and here using just GCC

Comment: Sounds like the windows shell indeed does not understand back ticks: that's something I can't help with, sorry. For the other error: Don't put `example-0.c` in any bin directory (unless that's really where you want store your own files). Something like C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\My Documents\gtk-example\ maybe? And as I said: be in that same directory when you compile.